# Android asynctask won't accept context

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I have a strange problem.  I am trying to change a TextView but cannot `findViewById`, it says that the `findViewById` cannot be resolved. I have a Main Activity from which I am calling `AsyncTask(Context context)`. In the constructor I pass this from main activity, I have already tried with Main Activity.getContext() but it still doesn't work.

Any help is welcome.

```
public class UcitavanjeUpozadini extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private UcitavanjeHelperKlasa helperKlasa;
private List<OglasHelper> lista;

public UcitavanjeUpozadini(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.progressDialog = null;
    this.helperKlasa = new UcitavanjeHelperKlasa();
    this.lista = new ArrayList<OglasHelper>();

}
```

Comment: Need some code for the AsyncTask in order to help

Comment: Show some code, however it's not a good idea to pass an Activity context to an AsyncTask .. this can easily lead to null pointer exceptions and memory leaks.

Comment: i ve updated the question with the code

Comment: Mark so is it better then to implement the asynctask class as a inner class in my main activity?

Comment: I would look at AsyncTaskLoader, or using an AsyncTask with a headless fragment (do a google search tonnes of examples) basically an AsyncTask should not be directly used with anything that could be destroyed and recreated on configuration changes (like activities and fragments). AsyncTask and a headless Fragment gets around this by using `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreate()` of a Fragments callback/life cycle method.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this if you have an activity, change the TextView value in onPostExecute:

```
private MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            mTextView.setText("text changed before background operation");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
            //perform your background operations changing the paramaters 
            //and return type accordingly
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            mTextView.setText("text changed after background operation");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to put the AsyncTask in a separate file, you could add a callback to an interface implemented in your Activity or pass the TextView to the AsyncTask during the instantiation

Comment: @zomlaaa95 I'm glad i helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a fragment or in an activity? Have you tried getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Probably not a fragment ... "In the constructor I pass THIS from main activity" - quoted from question.

Comment: it is in a ordinary class, and yes i have tried and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

findViewById isn't a function of Context, its a function of Activity.  Generally you should pass in the view directly rather than an Activity and call findViewById on it.

Comment: How would I pass the view from the main activity? Give me some code please

Comment: As a parameter in the constructor